# Publicly expose post of Rancher hosted app

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, rancher

How can I publicly expose the port of a Rancher hosted app?

The app is deployed from this helm chart: https://bitnami.com/stack/rabbitmq/helm. My goal is to expose the amqp port 5672 publicly, so that is accessible via hostname:port.

Comment: did you go through chart configuration values? https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq/#installing-the-chart

Answer (score 0):

I answered this during the [June EMEA Rancher Office Hours](https://youtu.be/93O9_Aojal4) session.

If you're using the nginx Ingress Controller (the default for RKE), you can open tcp/5672 by editing the `tcp-services` ConfigMap in the `ingress-nginx` namespace. Add a value to the `data` key like this:

```
  "port": namespace/service:port
```

If your rabbitmq workload is running in the "rabbitmq" namespace and there is a ClusterIP service called "rabbitmq-service" listening on port 5672, then your entry would look like:

```
  "5672": rabbitmq/rabbitmq-service:5672
```

The ingress controller will open a TCP port and pass traffic through to the specified service.